# Execute batch file duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found

Tags: c#, batch-file, cmd

Executing by **C#** a complicated **batch** file, that setting session variables example

```
SET TEST = rainbow
```

getting the famous

```
A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found.
```

I used

```
string args = string.Format("/k \"cd /d {0} && {1}\"", s.Path, s.Filename + " " + userChoice);
    RunBatch("cmd.exe", args, s.Path);
.
.
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            WorkingDirectory = workingDir,
            FileName = cmd,
            Arguments = cmdArgs
        };

        Process.Start(startInfo);
```

when trying it on simple batch file working. With the complex one getting the error mention above.

--

I tried also to **write** by C#, a **new** batch file that has on the first line the

```
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
```

, then calling the needed one, and execute this batch by **C#**, the error again is the same...

any tip?

Comment: `SET TEST = rainbow` sets a variable named `TEST` + _space_ to the value _space_ + `rainbow`, which is most probably not what you want, so better use `set "TEST=rainbow"`…

Comment: @aschipfl - correct, because Im running the batch on other PC, I wrote it  'on the fly' sure no spaces should be



today I checked also the ShellExecute API, the result is the same...